# Fiddler 2 to rebuild encrypted request

Tags: httprequest, fiddler

Say Fiddler 2 captured a encrypted request, like this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/report.php?encrypted_text?qwQEHGRq1t
```

With Fiddler Request Builder, I can resend this request to reproduce. Also, in Fiddler Inspector, I can see the original form value (before encrypted). Is there any way to use Request Builder to modify the original form value and send the new encrypted request? Please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but you don't want to use the Request Builder to do it.  The Request Builder is for creating new requests.  What you want to do is set a breakpoint on the outbound request then fiddle with it before sending it on to the server.

Here are a couple of different ways to do that:

1. Rules > Automatic Breakpoints > Before Requests
2. In the quickexec box (the black box at the bottom) type "bpu report.php".  Now Fiddler will stop at a breakpoint before all requests to any URL that contains "report.php".  Type "bpu" with no parameters to clear the breakpoint.
3. Programmatically tamper with the request using FiddlerScript.  The best documentation for FiddlerScript is on the official site: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/dev/